# Where is Rsync's default temp directory?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, backup, rsync

I'm using rsync to backup files to an external hard drive; my boot disk is pretty full. Rsync keeps failing due to not enough disk space to build the temporary file list, and unfortunately doesn't delete the temp files. My question: where are those temporary files kept? I'd like to go and delete them manually.

Comment: Have a look at `-T, --temp-dir=DIR` in [man rsync](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/rsync.1.html), it says, "The default behavior is to create each temporary file in the same directory as the associated destination file.".  Otherwise I'd look in the systems `$TMPDIR`.

Comment: Yea, I read the man page and googled a bit before asking. In this case, it's definitely not on the external device as my free space plummeted during the rsync. I cleared out both tmp directories, to no avail.

Comment: you could try running rsync and using `lsof /|grep rsync` to determine where the files being used by it are

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured it out.

I was running a simple rsync command: `rsync -av /Users/kenneth /foo`
where `/foo` is the former location of an external drive. Instead of directing rsync to the current location, I was creating a new location and writing to it, simply duplicating files on my boot drive.

Lesson: read your command twice and double-check before running it.